# Extracting salary information from job descriptions (R)

Tags: r, string, web-scraping, dplyr, stringr

In a dataset of scraped job description, I am interested in extracting the salary or salary range figures, which are often mentioned under the "description" column.

Each row in the df is a single job description.

```
# Print data example with specific columns
dput(job_posts[1:8,c(2,11)])
```

output:

```
structure(list(description = c("الشروط والمؤهلات :\n\nخبره ومعرفة بالتجارة الالكترونية لاتقل عن سنة\n\nالمؤهل بكالوريوس\n\nJob Type: Full-time\n\nSalary: ﷼5,000.00 - ﷼7,000.00 per month\n\nAbility to commute/relocate:\n\n* Riyadh: Reliably commute or planning to relocate before starting work (Preferred)", 
"موقع المعرض: الرياض\n\nاستقبال العملاء والتوجيه داخل أقسام المتجر. تقديم معلومات دقيقة مثل ميزات\nالمنتج ، والأسعار وخدمات ما بعد البيع. التجاوب مع العملاء فيما يخص المنتجات\nوالخدمات. اظهار المقارنات بين الأسعار والميزات الاضافية لتشجيع العملاء على\nالشراء. إعداد وتجهيز العروض الترويجية المختلفة. الاشراف على اجراءات الاسترجاع\nواستبدال المنتجات. تعريف العملاء بأحدث العروض والخصومات الخاصة بشكل مستمر.\nتقديم تقارير دورية عن ملاحظات العملاء إلى مدير المتجر. الإطلاع بشكل دائم على\nالمنتجات والخدمات الجديدة. \nنوع الوظيفة: دوام كامل\n\nنوع الوظيفة: دوام كامل, لحديثي التخرج\n\nالراتب: ﷼4,000.00 - ﷼4,300.00 لكل شهر\n\nسؤال (أسئلة) طلب التقدم:\n\n* سعودي/ة\n* متفرغ\n* سكان وسط أوشمال الرياض؟\n\nتاريخ البدء المتوقع: 20/03/2023", 
"Job description\n\nWe are looking for project Engineer with 7 years' experience at least in KSA\n\n* KSA Driving license Holder\n* BSc in Engineering with minimum 7 years experience in Construction and Management of the site team.\n* responsible for all technical and engineering aspects of their assigned projects. They plan, schedule, predict, and manage all the technical tasks of their assigned project to assure accuracy, proper resources, and quality from start to finish.\n* Familiar with various construction methods and materials, their characteristics, installation procedures\n* Advanced computer proficiency in MS Office applications, Access, Autocad, Prolog Manager and Primavera\n* Skills in writing technical and progress reports for site visits.\n* Capable of carrying out site HSE and Quality audits on a regular basis\n* Good communication skills in English (verbal and written)\n* Excellent leadership and teamwork skills\n\nنوع الوظيفة: دوام كامل, دائم, عقد\n\nمدة العقد: 24 شهر\n\nالراتب: من AED6,500.00 لكل شهر\n\nالتعليم:\n\nبكالوريوس (مطلوب)\n\nالخبرة:\n\nProject Engineer: 6 سنوات (مطلوب)\n\nWorking in Mega projects: 3 سنوات (مطلوب)\n\nالترخيص/الشهادة:\n\nValid driving license (مطلوب)\n\nJob Types: Full-time, Contract \nContract length: 24 months\n\nSalary: ﷼6,500.00 per month\n\nAbility to commute/relocate:\n\n* Riyadh: Reliably commute or planning to relocate before starting work (Required)\n\nEducation:\n\n* Bachelor's (Required)\n\nExperience:\n\n* Working as Project Engineer: 6 years (Required)\n* Working in mega projects: 3 years (Required)\n\nLicense/Certification:\n\n* Driving License (Required)", 
"Your Role and Responsibilities\n\n* Creation of new NSX-T construct as and when required\n* Firewall rules configuration\n* Onboarding VMs under NSX-T platform (VLAN to Geneve)\n* Troubleshoot VMware NSX-T related issues alongside Customer administrators\n* Configuration changes with NSX-T to support daily operations\n* Raise VMware support Tickets, if required\n* Conduct guidance sessions about VMware NSX-T\n* Assist with the lifecycle management (minor upgrades only) of NSX-T\n\nCoaching and knowledge transfer\n\nQualifications \nVMware NSX Experience \nFluent English is a must\n\nRequired Skills \nVMware Workspace ONE - 2 years, VMware/KVM/ESX/Xen - 2 years, VMware - 2 years\n\nIT & DevOps Roles \nIT Infrastructure \nSystems Administrator\n\nBenefits\n\nCandidates will be based on Saudi Arabia\n\nSalary range : max 18- 20 SAR\n\nAny nationality preferred based in KSA\n\nJob Type: Full-time\n\nPay: ﷼18,000.00 - ﷼20,000.00 per month\n\nApplication Deadline: 20/03/2023", 
"* ForgeRock Developer\n* Budget: 18k SAR\n* Location: KSA (Riyadh)\n* Client: Aujas\n* Positions: 3\n* Proven experience with ForgeRock products, more specifically Forgerock AM, IG, DS and IDM (preferable).\n* Experience of writing custom java components using Forgerock SDK to meet business requirements (e.g. modules, trees, STS, policies, connectors, scripts etc.); test it for both functional and robustness and move it into production\n\nBe responsible for implementing and maintaining identity\nfederation/synchronisation and Single Sign On across different\nclients/solutions.\n\n* Develop and maintain authorization and authentication trees/nodes, chains and policies based on business use cases\n* Development experience a must - No operations and support CVs.\n\nInterested can WhatsApp on 9512469394\n\nJob Type: Full-time\n\nSalary: Up to ﷼18,000.00 per month\n\nAbility to commute/relocate:\n\n* Riyadh: Reliably commute or planning to relocate before starting work (Required)\n\nExperience:\n\n* Forgerock: 7 years (Preferred)\n* Forgerock AM, IG, DS: 7 years (Preferred)\n* IDM: 7 years (Preferred)\n* Forgerock SDK to meet business requirements: 7 years (Preferred)\n* Development: 7 years (Preferred)\n\nSpeak with the employer \n+91 9512469394", 
"إن جسر المعلومات هو مزود هاتف معروف عالميًا ويتطلع الآن إلى التوسع! مهمتنا هي\nتقديم أعلى جودة من الخدمة لجميع منتجاتنا ونحن نبحث الآن عن شركاء محليين جدد!\nهذه فرصتك لاتخاذ خطوتك الأولى في عالم التكنولوجيا العالية.\n\nيتضمن العمل توقيع اتفاق مع مزود خدمة الهاتف المحلي مثل Mobily و Zain و STC وما\nإلى ذلك. إعداد جهاز مخصص ، تدفعه Info Bridge ، والدعم اليومي للجهاز. سيتم\nتوفير مزيد من التفاصيل عبر الهاتف.\n\nيشمل العمل - - إعداد جهاز في موقعك المفضل - كل المعاملات مع شركة الاتصال تتم\nعن طريقنا - وجود اتصال ثابت بالإنترنت - دعم العمل اليومي بما في ذلك إصلاح\nمشاكل الاتصال والمزيد\n\nمتطلبات - - مواطن سعودي فقط (يجب أن تكون صاحب شركة) - - اذا لم يكن لديك\nمؤسسة/شركة يوجد إمكانية فتح مؤسسة عن طريقنا وكل التكاليف علينا - التوفر خلال\nالنهار لدعم الجهاز - الاستعداد للعمل من المنزل والحصول على دخل ثابت ومستقر.\n\nنحن نعمل مع رجال الأعمال فقط ، يجب أن يكون لديك مؤسسة محلية حتى تتمكن من العمل\nمعنا. ستدفع الشركة جميع النفقات بما في ذلك الاشتراك السنوي والضرائب والإعداد\nمع مزود محلي وأي نفقات ذات صلة.\n\nمعنا ستحول تطلعاتك إلى حقيقة. سنساعد في تشكيل رحلتك من خلال إثراء الخبرات وفرص\nالتعلم والتطوير والتعرض لمهام مختلفة ضمن دورك أو من خلال التنقل الداخلي. تقدم\nمجموعتنا مسارات وظيفية متنوعة لاناس استثنائيين ، كل يوم.\n\nنوع الوظيفة: دوام جزئي, عقد \nمدة العقد: 12 شهر \nساعات الدوام الجزئي: 10 كل أسبوع\n\nالراتب: من ﷼3,000.00 لكل شهر", 
"Full Job Description \nWe are looking for a competent Administrative Associate to help with the\norganization and running of the daily administrative operations of the\ncompany.\n\nResponsibilities\n\n* Organize office and assist associates in ways that optimize procedures\n* Sort and distribute communications in a timely manner\n* Create and update records ensuring accuracy and validity of information\n* Schedule and plan meetings and appointments\n* Monitor level of supplies and handle shortages\n* Resolve office-related malfunctions and respond to requests or issues\n* Coordinate with other departments to ensure compliance with established policies\n* Maintain trusting relationships with suppliers, customers and colleagues\n* Perform receptionist duties when needed.\n* Responsible of ensuring all company licences are updated.\n* Responsible for governmental platforms operations.\n\nPersonal attributes\n\n* Self-motivated.\n* Dynamic, energetic and positive attitude.\n* Confident.\n* Presentable and personable.\n* Excellent communication skills.\n* Innovative drive.\n* Works well under pressure.\n* Attention to detail.\n\nProfessional attributes\n\n* Strong planning and organizing skills.\n* Strong collaboration and time management skills.\n* Ability to work in a complex matrix management model.\n* Great Microsoft office skills.\n* High standard of formal correspondence and business correspondence in English and Arabic required.\n* Practical experience is a must have, preferably with support services of a consulting firm for a minimum of 4 years.\n\nAttributes that might give you an edge\n\n* Bi-lingual capabilities (English and Arabic).\n* Driving License (must)\n\nMinimum qualifications\n\n* Preferably Saudi National\n* Bachelor's degree in Business Administration with GPA>4.50\n* Fresh graduates are welcome to apply\n* 0-2 years of relevant experience\n\nJob Types: Full-time, Permanent, Contract \nContract length: 12 months\n\nAbility to commute/relocate:\n\n* Riyadh: Reliably commute or planning to relocate before starting work (Required)", 
"Us\n\nThe ENTERTAINER is a leading digital company whose main goal is to add value\nto consumers by bringing them the best incentive offers globally. We are a\ndata-driven, 100% digital, tech company. Providing first-rate offers across\nrenowned dining, leisure, entertainment and hotel brands worldwide, the\nENTERTAINER has grown with the aim of creating unbeatable value and loyalty\neverywhere we go. We believe that \"experience is everything\", resulting in our\npassion for creating unforgettable experiences for both our customers,\npartners and employees.\n\nResponsibilities\n\n* Undertake daily administrative tasks to ensure the functionality and coordination of the department's activities\n* Support marketing executives in organizing various projects\n* Conduct market research and analyze consumer rating reports/ questionnaires\n* Must be good with Analytics (social media, web analytics, rankings etc.)\n* Update spreadsheets, databases and inventories with statistical, financial and non-financial information\n* Assist in the organizing of promotional events and traditional or digital campaigns and attend them to facilitate their success\n* Prepare and deliver promotional presentations\n* Compose and post online content on the company's website and social media accounts\n* Write Engagement literature (brochures, press releases etc) to augment the company's presence in the market\n* Communicate directly with clients and encourage trusting relationships\n\nRequirements and skills\n* Saudi national\n* Experience as a marketing assistant\n* Strong command of the Arabic & English written & spoken language \n* Good understanding of office management and Engagement Principles\n* Demonstrable ability to multi-task and adhere to deadlines\n* Well-organized with a customer-oriented approach\n* Good knowledge of market research techniques and databases\n* Excellent knowledge of MS Office, marketing computer software and online applications (CRM tools, Online analytics, Google Adwords etc.)\n* Exquisite communication and people skills\n* High School diploma; BSc in Marketing, Business or relevant field is a strong advantage\n\nLHqhHB84IB"
), estimated_salary = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

looking at the data, I could see that most companies mention salary after the words, "salary" or "الراتب" in Arabic. I want to create a new column called "salary", with the salary/wage amount per job post, so I created the function below, but for some reason I am unable to capture salary figures.

```
salary_finder = function(string){
 
  salary = c(" ")
  split_string = strsplit(string, split = NULL)
  split_string = split_string[[1]]
  flag = 0
 
    for(letter in split_string){
      if(flag > 0){salary = append(salary, letter)}
      if(letter == "الراتب"){flag = 1}
      if(letter == "salary"){flag = 1}
      if(letter == " "){flag = flag-0.5}
    }
  salary = paste(salary, collapse = '')
  return(salary)
}


for(n in 1:length(job_posts$description)){
  job_posts$salary[n] <- salary_finder(job_posts$description[n])
}


job_posts %>%
  view()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to tune your function without much modification.

1. Note that with `strsplit(string, split = NULL)` the outcome is letters not words whereas your function matches words

maybe you need some cleaning before calling the finder function ?

here my proposition

```
tag="﷼"
salary_finder = function(string){
  
  salary = c(" ")
  string=tolower(string)
  split_string = strsplit(string, split = " |\n")
  split_string = split_string[[1]]
  
  for(i in 1:length(split_string)) {
    letter=split_string[i]
    if(str_detect(letter,tag)) {salary = split_string[i]}
      }
  return(salary)
}
df$salary=NA
for(n in 1:length(df$description)){
  df$salary[n] <- salary_finder(df$description[n])
}
```

and the resulting df

[image]

2. Note that there is no local money tag in the last 2 `df$description`
3. Note also that the `salary_finder` fuction will return the last word with the local money tag as the new detected value overwrites the old one.

so you have some work left